# Get bot's status discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py, status

I'd like to get the bot's status whenever it is changed to make an action (for now it's just print when it comes online.).

Unfortunately my approach doesn't work:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(usr_before, usr_after):
    if bot.user.status == discord.Status.online:
        print("becomes online!")
```

I think the problem is that the status isn't a `User` attribute but a `Member` attribute. How can I "convert" my bot to a `Member`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it like this.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
print("Bot Online!")
print("Name: {}".format(client.user.name))
print("ID: {}".format(client.user.id))
await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="d!help for help"))
```

try this:

```
member = None
for server in bot.servers:
    member = server.get_member(bot.user.id)
    break

if member.status == discord.Status.online:
```

or this:

```
if [s for s in bot.servers][0].get_member(bot.user.id).status == discord.Status.online:
```

Comment: Actually, I already have a command that changes presence. What I would like to do is, meanwhile, have an event that does something (here something on the console) when my bot has a specific status.

Comment: `bot.servers(0).get_member(bot.user.id)` should give you a member object of your bot. Just take the first server in the bots server list and use function to get a member object. I personally don't know a better way to get the member object of the bot. Give it a try if you want to.

Comment: I got this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Théotime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Bots\Discord\@Testing bot#2592\launch bot.py", line 28, in on_member_update
    if bot.servers(0).get_member(bot.user.id).status == discord.Status.online:
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not callable`

Comment: `bot.servers.next().get_member(bot.user.id)` you could also try this

Comment: The interpreter says the dict object has no attribute next

Comment: Be aware that that is a member object of that exact server, it is probably diffrent for all servers. Keep that in mind :)

Comment: Okay, seems we can't do it in one line

Comment: I have updated my answer, if that won't work then I am out of possibilities

Comment: just out of intrest, have you tried the first one too? :)

Comment: wait i miscounted, I talked about this one :
`m = None
for s in bot.servers:
    m = s.get_member(bot.user.id)
    break

if m.status == discord.Status.online:`

I didn't test the other one though

Comment: seems like you had a rough day so far. If you ever try let me know what the result is :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Okay so actually, there's a discord.Server attribute (discord.Server.me) which does this x)

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.me

Haven't tested it though